# Generate random output with different variables

Tags: tcl

How can I make a random output of variables? I would like to randomly arrange and output the variable

```
bind pub -|- !random proc:random
proc proc:random {nick host handle channel arg} {

set output1 "test1"
set output2 "test2"
set output3 "test3"
set output4 "test4"
set output5 "test5"
set output6 "test6"
set output7 "test7"

set ouput "$output1 $output2 $output3 $output4 $output5 $output6 $output7"

putnow "PRIVMSG $channel :$ouput"
}
```

The output should look like this, for example:

The first time

```
set ouput "$output6 $output2 $output4 $output1 $output5 $output7 $output3"
```

The second time

```
set ouput "$output5 $output1 $output3 $output7 $output2 $output4 $output6"
```

The third time

```
set ouput "$output2 $output7 $output6 $output1 $output3 $output5 $output4"
```

Comment: You're looking for [shuffling a list](https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/Shuffle+a+list). There are several examples of how to implement a shuffle procedure there. You can pick one of your liking.

Comment: [`::struct::list shuffle`](https://core.tcl-lang.org/tcllib/doc/trunk/embedded/md/tcllib/files/modules/struct/struct_list.md#8) from tcllib.

Comment: If you're ever tempted to have numerically sequenced variables like this, automatically choose to a list instead. That advice applies for any language with a list/array data type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either you want a random shuffle or you want to progress round a series of permutations. The former is far easier to implement, as you need less persistent state, and Tcllib already has a random shuffler for you.

```
# This is part of Tcllib
package require struct::list

bind pub -|- !random proc:random
proc proc:random {nick host handle channel arg} {
    set randomItems {
        "test1"
        "test2"
        "test3"
        "test4"
        "test5"
        "test6"
        "test7"
    }

    set output [struct::list shuffle $randomItems]
    putnow "PRIVMSG $channel :$output"
}
```

There are lots of other ways to generate the list to be shuffled too. Using a big literal is just very very easy...

(Note that it is conventional to put `package require` calls outside procedures at the top of your script so that they're easy to find when visually scanning the file. Tcl doesn't enforce this and *won't ever* enforce it, but it's definitely good style.)